# Visual Studio 2005 Does Not build the exe file , what should I do?

Tags: c#, build-error

In visual studio 2005 , whenever I hit the build button the exe file does not update , and if i press rebuild , the old exe file is deleted but no new exe file is generated , I checked the path , it's correct. what should I do? I have tried everything.

Though it just happens to some of the solutions , the others work fine , and just may not get updated sometimes

it is crucial due to the changes I made to the newer versions of it

Comment: Please check the build action for the project

Comment: did you try "rebuild" instead of "build"?

Comment: Does your solution compile?

Comment: close your Visual Studio and start it again, then clean the solution and rebuild it...sometimes this also works.

Comment: Make sure you are checking the right directory based on your configuration profile.  If you are in `Debug` you need to check the `bin\Debug` directory.   If you are in `Release`, you need to check the `bin\Release` directory.

Comment: anyone read the details???? I already told rebuild deletes any old exe and does not create a new one, and i am in the right directory , i guess it doesn't compile , the vshost.exe file is created upon build/rebuild but not the exe itself , i closed and reopened it several times , it's no use

Comment: if it doesn't compile, what do you expect to have in .exe?

Comment: what gets written in the visual studio output window?

Answer (score 0):

ok i figured what is wrong , it's a problem i guess you encounter in earlier versions , in 2010 version of Microsoft VS the program tells you because of existing errors it is not possible to build/debug the program , but in 2005 version it tries to build\rebuild it , and if there are any mistakes ,the old .exe file is deleted , and if you try debugging without builing/rebuilding it will run the old .exe , so this is a disadvantage of using older versions